# Выполнение функций до ввода слова, например "Stop"

Tags: python, циклы, планировщик-задач, scheduler

Уже не первый день пытаюсь решить проблему с тем, чтобы можно было выйти из цикла при вводе слова, но при этом не блокировать выполнение функции. Возможно мой вопрос не нов, но я нигде не нашел ответ. Изучал планировщики, но не смог понять как выйти из цикла принудительно, при вводе слова. input() в цикле While True: не вариант.

Comment: Использовать потоки

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Есть полезная [статья](https://habr.com/ru/post/149420/) на хабре, там рассказывается о модуле Threading для Python (Простыми словами это многопоточность, или же ещё проще, выполнение вашей функции одновременно. Более точную информацию вы узнаете как раз токи в этой статье).

А для принудительного выхода из цикла, используйте `break`.